# Spring boot App: appending a string to an existing txt file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to append a string to an existing file.txt in spring boot app.
my file is located under resources(src/main/resources/file.txt).

I have tried this using **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils**

```
public static boolean addWord(String word) {

        if(!wordExist(word, getFileName())) {
            File file = new File(getFileName());
            try {
                Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(readLines(new File(getFileName())));
                words.add(word);
                FileUtils.writeLines(file,words);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
}
```

This works fine, but when I restart the server the file rollback. it seems like the strings are not added to file.txt permanently. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: method writeLines close its FileOutputStream and File class does not have close method

Comment: wait, do you want to append? cuz here you overwrite -- write(File file, CharSequence data, boolean append)

Comment: my guess is that you overwrite file somewhere at the start.

Comment: Actually, i read all strings from file into a Set<String> then add my new string to the Set,,then overwrite the existing file with the Set

Comment: I know. Check what else calls this code. Possible reasons: something calls it at start-up or something. ps: you can just append with: FileUtils.writeLines(file,word, true);

Comment: Oh! yes,  FileUtils.writeLines(file,word, true); is cool, i also call this code in the tests

Comment: if you use eclipse - right click on method and select "call hierarchy" to see what calls it. Alternatively - start, use, end AND THEN change the name inside getFileName(). After that repeat and see results. Also make sure it's not inside /target/ as that folder is cleared by maven/eclipse at some points

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out. The problem was that It was updating the file inside the jar file, so when I re-build I replace the file. So I moved the file to file server, then its working fine.

Comment: wow. How did it manage to put it in jar?

Comment: It was because I put it under src/main/resources